# ¿Como indicar valores de una fila con registros nulos a otra? SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaría saber como puedo indicar que los valores de un campo nulo, son de otro campo, pero el otro campo también posee valores, por lo que se deberían sumar, un ejemplo:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|Posicion |Nombre   |Valor    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|NULL     |NULL     |13       |
+---------+---------+---------+
|1        |Reg1     |7        |
+---------+---------+---------+
|2        |Reg2     |10       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

En el ejemplo, las columnas tienen valores que definen **posición**, **nombre** y **valor**, pero existen registros que poseen **posición** y **valor** en nulo, pero se tiene conocimiento que dichos registros pertenecen a la **posición** "2", sin embargo, **posición** 2 también posee valores, la cuestión es, como puedo indicar que los campos nulos con valores, pertenecen a la **posición** 2 y sumarlos con los que ya tiene **posicion** 2?.

Esto sería lo esperado:

```
+---------+---------+---------+
|Posicion |Nombre   |Valor    |
+---------+---------+---------+
|1        |Reg1     |7        |
+---------+---------+---------+
|2        |Reg2     |23       |
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Todos los nulos pertenecen siempre a la posición 2, o cómo es que los relacionas?

Answer (score 0):

Eso se hace usando un ISNULL() para definir el valor que deben tener los nulos.

```
SELECT ISNULL( Posicion, 2) AS Posicion,
       ISNULL( Nombre, 'Reg2') AS Nombre,
       SUM( Valor) AS Valor
FROM MiTabla
GROUP BY ISNULL( Posicion, 2),
         ISNULL( Nombre, 'Reg2');
```

También podrías usar COALESCE en vez de ISNULL pero debes investigar como difieren en su comportamiento.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que veo aquí es que quieres excluir de la consulta los registros cuyos campos tengan valores nulos, puedes filtrar por ejemplo:

```
Select * from nombreTabla where posicion is not null and nombre is not null and valor is not null;
```

Comment: Lee bien la pregunta, el AP no quiere excluir las filas con valores `null`.